# Unit Test in Play! Framework Application that does not require a test Play Server

Tags: java, testing, playframework-1.x

One option for running my tests in my Play! application is by executing the command `play auto-test`.

One of the ways Play seems to identify tests to run is to find all test classes with the super class `play.test.UnitTest` (or another Play equivalent).  Having a test class extend `UnitTest` seems to come with some overhead as shown by this bit of stuff spat out in the console:

```
INFO   info, Starting C:\projects\testapp\.
WARN   warn, Declaring modules in application.conf is deprecated. Use dependencies.yml instead (module.secure)
INFO   info, Module secure is available (C:\play-1.2.1\modules\secure)
INFO   info, Module spring is available (C:\projects\testapp\.\modules\spring-1.0.1)
WARN   warn, Actually play.tmp is set to null. Set it to play.tmp=none
WARN   warn, You're running Play! in DEV mode
INFO   info, Connected to jdbc:h2:mem:play;MODE=MYSQL;LOCK_MODE=0
INFO   info, Application 'Test App' is now started !
```

Obviously having a Play environment for tests that requires such a setup is useful, however, if I have a test class that tests production code that executes logic that does not require a Play environment I don't want to have to extend `UnitTest` so that I can avoid the overhead of starting up a Play environment.

If I have a test class that does not extend `UnitTest` then it does not get executed by the command `play auto-test`.  Is there a way to get the `play auto-test` command to execute all tests regardless of whether I extend Play's `UnitTest`?

**Edit:** Someone has actually raised a [ticket](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/1074-feature-request-run-junit-tests-not-extending-basetest) for this very issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the short answer: no. A tad longer answer: no unless you change code in the framework. The autotest is an Ant task that sets the server and triggers the testing, but it's not using the  ant task, so it won't detect (by default) your 'normal' unit tests.

You have two options: either you add an extra task to the Ant file of Play to run unit tests via the  task (you will need to include the relevant jars too) or you edit the code used to launch the Play test environment.

Both imply changing the framework to a certain level. Although giving that you are using Play, I wonder why you should not have all your tests follow the Play pattern...

Comment: Well I have some tests that may test classes that don't require any "play" features.  Let's say I have a Math class that has a method called "int add(int left, int right)".  The notion of adding two numbers shouldn't require that I have a play test environment.

Comment: @digiarnie I understand, but the idea behind testing is to run all of them at once to ensure everything is ok, so in that scenario it makes sense :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say there.  My problem is that auto-test "doesn't" run all of the tests unless I extend UnitTest.  As you said the idea behind testing is to run all of them at once.  "play auto-test" ignores tests not extending UnitTest (or some other play superclass)...

Comment: Ok, what I mean is that you have some code that you are using inside Play. You want to run all the tests of that project at once. Play autotest only recognizes "Play tests". But if your code is being used there, in a Play project, it makes sense to turn your tests "Play Tests" as you want to run them along the other tests of the project. It's simpler (or should be) than the other way around. By not using the Play test format in code used inside Play, you are breaking "convention over configuration" of the framework, and I can't see why in this case that would be a requirement :)

Comment: one reason: running an individual test in eclipse takes forever if it has to start play. It would be excellent if `play test` found other tests and included them optionally.

Comment: I found that extending to UnitTest and using an @RunWith(Enclosed.class) for example does make it show up and run with play unit tests, yet not using the play test runner in your IDE. Hacky though...

Answer (score 0):

If these tests doesn't require any Play! feature, why don't you put them on a library ? With your example (math add) : create a calculator.jar package, and build it with Ant or Maven after running tests. 
Like this, you can use your library in several Play! projects (or Spring, Struts, ... if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't get why the problem itself is even debatable. Having simple and small unit tests (even in the web-part of your project) is the most normal thing to do.
The extra overhead of framework initialisation slows down your roundtrips significantly if you have many tests. As it can be seen in the ticket, the current workaround is to **make your unit tests extend org.junit.Assert instead of play.test.UnitTest**